# How to pass conditional array to wp_localize_script

Tags: array, conditional-tags, wp-localize-script

I'm trying to generate a custom `array` from a PHP function to pass on `wp_localize_script` but I seem to not be able to set page conditionals.

I have the following function:

```php
function mb_scripts_settings() {

    // blanks
    $mb_ajax_form_type = $mb_get_page_slug = $mb_redirect = $mb_redirect_time = $mb_form_disable = $mb_array = '';


    // get the form type
    $mb_ajax_form_type      = ( is_front_page() ? 'change'  : 'submit'  );

    // get the page
    $mb_get_page_slug       = get_page_link();

    // generate the url for redirection
    $mb_form_area           = ( ( is_page('admin') && isset($_GET['mbtab']) )   ? $_GET['mbtab']    : null  );
    $mb_form_area_url       = ( empty($mb_form_area)    ? '/' : '/admin/?mbtab=' . $mb_form_area . '&mbform=1'          );

    // if the page is admin
    if( is_page('admin') ) {
        $mb_redirect        = true;
        $mb_redirect_time   = 3000;
        $mb_form_disable    = true;
    }

    // if the page is password set
    if( is_page('pw') ) {
        $mb_redirect        = true;
        $mb_redirect_time   = 3000;
        $mb_form_disable    = true;
    }

    // if the page is front
    if( is_page('pw') ) {
        $mb_redirect        = false;
        $mb_redirect_time   = 0;
        $mb_form_disable    = false;
        $mb_form_area = $mb_form_area_url = '';
    }

    // build the array
    $mb_array = array( $mb_ajax_form_type, $mb_get_page_slug, $mb_redirect, $mb_redirect_time, $mb_form_disable );

    return $mb_array;
}
```

However, I am getting an error saying I can't call `is_front_page` or `is_page` outside of the loop.

`Notice: is_front_page was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.)`

I have tried to do this by getting the page id and then the slug from that but it hasn't returned any results - always blank in the `mb_get_page_slug`

```php
function mb_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mbtheme_js', mbWebOS_js . 'theme-scripts. '.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'mbtheme_js', 'mbtheme_js', mb_scripts_settings() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',   'mb_scripts'        );
```

Comment: In what hook do you call `mb_scripts_settings()` ? Is it `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: Where is `mb_scripts_settings()` running? Where is `wp_localize_script()`?

Comment: @SallyCJ added it, sorry thought I had!

Comment: Other than the typo in the code, your code seems fine to me. What's the exact error message? But you can try installing Query Monitor and visit the page in question, then inspect the Query Monitor results.

Comment: @SallyCJ the error is: `Notice: is_front_page was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.)`

Comment: In that case, try `wp_reset_postdata()` or `wp_reset_query()` at the top of your function... but that means there's another code which isn't resetting the global `$post` or `$wp_query`, so you'd need to fix that.

Comment: @SallyCJ neither seem to work. It is being called before anything is loading, but thought you'd be able to run conditional checks first for scripts

Comment: What page gives you that error? A single Page/Post/term? A category/search page? Are you developing a theme or plugin? In what file you put the code? Sorry for the many questions.. but try to include as much details as possible.

Comment: @SallyCJ not sure what’s happened but i wrote it all again and now it works. potentially a rogue character or just missed a letter.

Comment: Well, that can happen sometimes... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this as the function:

```php
// set up the settings for the theme.js
function mb_scripts_settings() {

    // blanks
    $mb_ajax_form_type = $mb_get_page_slug = $mb_redirect = $mb_redirect_time = $mb_form_disable = $mb_array = '';

    // get the form type
    $mb_ajax_form_type      = ( is_front_page() ? 'change'  : 'submit'  );

    // get the page slug from ID
    $mb_get_page_slug       = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_the_ID() );

    // if the page is admin or password
    if( is_page( array('admin', 'pw') ) ) {
        $mb_redirect        = true;
        $mb_redirect_time   = 3000;
        $mb_form_disable    = true;

        if( is_page('admin') ) {
            // generate the url for redirection
            $mb_form_area           = ( ( is_page('admin') && isset($_GET['mbtab']) )   ? $_GET['mbtab']    : null      );
            $mb_form_area_url       = ( empty($mb_form_area)    ? '/' : '/admin/?mbtab=' . $mb_form_area . '&mbform=1'  );
            $mb_form_area_url       = get_home_url( $mb_form_area_url );
        }
    }

    // if the page is front
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        $mb_redirect        = false;
        $mb_redirect_time   = 0;
        $mb_form_disable    = false;
        $mb_get_page_slug   = 'front_page';
        $mb_form_area = $mb_form_area_url = null;
    }

    // build the array
    $mb_array = array(
                $mb_ajax_form_type,
                $mb_get_page_slug,
                $mb_redirect,
                $mb_redirect_time,
                $mb_form_disable
            );

    return $mb_array;
}
```

And when enqueuing the script:

```php
    // enqueue the theme js
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mb_mbtheme_js', mbWebOS_js . 'scripts.' . $mbTheme . '.js' );

    // localise the theme js
    // only for selected pages
    if( is_page('admin') || is_front_page() ) {
        wp_localize_script( 'mb_mbtheme_js', 'mb_mbtheme_js', mb_scripts_settings() );
    }
```